# Selenium Webdriver cookie/use web browser already open

Tags: selenium

I have 2 questions:

- I've builded a selenium webdriver script that works right but he opens a new instance of Firefox. Is it possible to use a Firefox that is already open? If it's yes, how?
- I need to send informations to the site, to keep my session active. I've thinking to use cookie and sending a request every 10 minutes. I don't know if it's a good idea...(I can't use selenium authentification, because the site generate a table with numbers like for bank site)

If anyone could give me some support...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Seleium2/WebDriver then you can create the start the browser instance one by calling `new FirefoxDriver()`, It can then be reused over multiple tests. For e.g if you are using JUNIT then you can create the `FirefoxDriver` driver in `@BeforeClass` and quit it in `@AfterClass`.

**browserSessionReuse**

The below SO post will explain why the session might be expiring. It might also depend upon how you wrote your test case (may be you are initializing it in the `setUp()` method).
[Selenium in -browserSessionReuse mode launchs a new browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099521/selenium-in-browsersessionreuse-mode-launchs-a-new-browser)

**NOTE:** It is always better to isolate the tests by creating and shutting down the browser instance per each test.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your response Pangea.

Comment: From selenium server help documentation 
-browserSessionReuse: stops re-initialization and spawning of the browser between tests . I tried to run 2 tests manually but it didn't run in the same session. Is this for a different purpose?

Comment: @devilnight updated the post with answers to your 1 questions

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened an instance of FireFox Browser by using firefox webdriver in your test case and you have not closed that instance, you can use that instance with RemoteWebDriver. You can even use that instance if one test case is failed and you want to start the other test case manually.
use this code.

```
IWebDriver WebDriver = null;

try
{
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://localhost:7055/hub");
WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
Console.WriteLine("Executed on remote driver");

}

catch (Exception)
{

WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
Console.WriteLine("Executed on New FireFox driver");

}
```

see the details here in this blog post. 
http://binaryclips.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/selenium-web-driver-in-c-how-to-continue-script-on-the-already-opened-browser-instance/